# In the Hopf fibration, does the total space remain unchanged if fiber and base spacec interchanged

Tags: fiber-bundles, hopf-fibration

In a fiber bundle, when we interchange the base space and fiber, does it result in a different total space? What if the base space and fiber are both spheres?

Take the bundle $S^1 \hookrightarrow S^3 \rightarrow S^2$. Here $S^1$ is the fiber and $S^2$ is the base space. If I now consider bundle
$ S^2 \hookrightarrow X \rightarrow S^1$, my question is whether $X$ is in anyway related to $S^3$, which is the total space before the interchange of the fiber and bases space. Of course, there is a trivial bundle $ S^2 \hookrightarrow X \rightarrow S^1$ but I am asking about any non-trivila ones.

Comment: What does it mean to "interchange the base space and fiber"? Are you under the impression the total space is determined by the base and fiber, and thus asking what bundle would have $S^2$ fibers and $S^1$ base? To be clear, it is not true that base and fiber determine total space; $S^1\times S^2$ and $S^3$ both are bundles with base $S^2$ and fiber $S^1$ but are not homeomorphic, after all. But in the case of base $S^1$ and fiber $S^2$, I think the only bundle is actually the trivial one (direct product).

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: There are two $S^2$-bundles over $S^1$, the trivial one $S^2\times S^1$, and a non-trivial one which is sometimes denotes $S^2\widetilde{\times} S^1$, which is non-orientable. Neither of these is $S^3$.

Comment: What kind of an operation is that $\tilde{\times}$

Comment: @EdenZane:  It's not a true operation in the sense that $M\tilde{\times}N$ is not defined for general $M$ and $N$.  But in situations where there are precisely two bundles with a given fiber and base, the notation is sometimes used to denote the non-trivial bundle.